# iTunes Match turning off occassionally

Tags: iphone, itunes-match, ios

I am experiencing weird problem with my iTunes Match subscription. Ever since upgrading to iOS 6 my devices spontaneously turn off iTunes Match this happened twice so far:

1. First shortly after upgrading my iPhone 4S and the new iPad to iOS 6. I upgraded, downloaded some songs and about a week later all my devices (inc. PC and a MacBook Pro) got iTunes Match turned off. This wasn't a problem for PC and MacBook as iTunes doesn't erase the music from them, but I had to download all the songs on iOS devices again.
2. Second time happened today - my PC and iPad got iTunes Match turned off. Again - no problem for PC, but have to download my music onto iPad all over again. You can imagine how time consuming this may be especially considering you cannot upload the music from desktop iTunes once you have iTunes Match on.

Any ideas why this might happen? There is absolutely no involvement from my side when this happens. All ma devices run latest Apple software (iTunes, OS X and iOS).

Where should I report it if I wanted to complain about it to Apple?

Comment: Same problem here! iTunes Match has spontaneously switched itself off on my iPhone 5. If I try to switch it back on, it tells me that it will replace all my songs. It took days to download them all the first time :(

Answer (score 1):

**Are you logging out of your Apple account?**

One possibility is that you are being logged out of your Apple account for some reason, either automatically or manually. If you are logging out of your account manually, then that's probably disabling iTunes Match because the service is attached with your account.

There are several situations in which you will be logged out of your Apple account automatically. For instance, when I first started using iTunes Match, I noticed that for some reason iTunes Match kept turning off. I later realized that it was because I had apps from different accounts installed (such as two accounts from different countries), so when I logged in to a different Apple account from the one that I use for iTunes Match so that I could update some of my apps, iTunes Match would disable itself.

**Try clearing the cache**

The cache could also be causing problems. I know that it this happens on the desktop version of iTunes; I'm not so sure if the iOS version also has cache problems, or at least I don't know if it's possible to clear any part of the cache on iOS.

To clear iTunes's cache, [here are some helpful instructions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3855768?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I did log out of my account on the phone a couple of weeks ago, and that may well be when iTunes Match turned itself off. The good news is, I just took the plunge and turned it back on - despite warning that it would, it doesn't seem to have deleted my music!